# JSON.Net deserializing from ESB

Tags: json.net

we receive a JSON string from our ESB that was converted from XML. Since the XML node has no type info, the converted string has data in it like...

"ClientId" : "13579"

The POCO we're deserializing in to has a property...

public int ClientId { get; set; }

Is there any way to tell the deserializer to parse the integer? Preference would be for no annotations in the POCO, and the deserializer should not have direct knowledge of the POCO type.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried it? It looks like it parses the integer automatically.

Comment: Yes, did try. Not exhaustively, though. Deeper attempts tomorrow. Hoping I'm missing something easy. I'm using JsonConverter static method, if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it DOES parse the integer, as Andrew mentioned. The issue was caused by the string having an extra set of "{" "}" surrounding the actual details. These appear to be the result of an XML->JSON conversion happening in the service bus layer. If those are removed, it all seems to be happy :)

Comment: Alternatively, the string can be parsed "as is" if you use the Parse/SelectToken/ToObject approach